# How to write style object to excel along with formatting using pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, styles

I have question further to question # 71499830.

```
import pandas as pd

def hl(d):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=d.columns, index=d.index)
    df.loc[d['BOX'].ne(d['BOX2']), ['BOX', 'BOX2']] = 'background: yellow'
    return df

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['one2', 'one3', 'one3', 'one4' ],
                   'Volume': [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 2.2],
                   'BOX': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],
                   'BOX2': ['one', 'two', 'five', 'one hundred']})
final_result_excel = r'C:\dummy_path\test_excel.xlsx'
df_new = df.style.apply(hl, axis=None)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(final_result_excel, engine= 'openpyxl')
df_new.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='TEST', index=False)
writer.save()
```

When I run above code, I am getting error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\python_scritp.py", line
18, in <module>
    df_new.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='TEST', index=False)   File "C:\Program
 Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py", line
 407, in to_excel
     formatter.write(   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line
 840, in write
     writer.write_cells(   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line
 457, in write_cells
     for cell in cells:   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line
 777, in get_formatted_cells
     for cell in itertools.chain(self._format_header(), self._format_body()):   File "C:\Program
 Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line
 677, in _format_regular_rows
     yield from self._generate_body(coloffset)   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line
 762, in _generate_body
     styles = self.styler._compute().ctx   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style_render.py",
 line 160, in _compute
     r = func(self)(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py", line
 1086, in _apply
     self._update_ctx(result)   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py", line
 966, in _update_ctx
     self.ctx[(i, j)].extend(css_list) TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Can any one guide me how to get the df_new along with the format to
excel without error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to write the style object created after df.style.apply(hl, axis=None) to excel (along with the formatting) but I am getting error mentioned in description.